Can't use managed switch as unmanaged switch
I have a ME-3400G-2CS-A that I am trying to use as an unmanaged switch. I read everywhere that when it is factory reset it should act as an unmanaged switch but I can not seem to use it interfaces just doesn't see each other. All interfaces are under same vlan and can't assign ip addresses to these 4 interfaces. Can anyone please provide some useful information on this ?
Output of show run ;
Building configuration...
Current configuration : 665 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
system mtu routing 1500
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 port-type nni
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 port-type nni
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
!
no ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
line con 0
line vty 5 15
!
end


Please add the switch's configuration to your question (output from show run in text format, using the editor's {} preformat option).

I added the output

As you can see from the show run output, not all interfaces are enabled.
So you will have to do some pre-configuration to make this act work as a “dumb” switch.
You can configure it once, save the configuration, and then every time it boots up it will be in the configuration you want.

Some managed switches work right out of the box like an unmanaged one, some do require some configuration in any case.
On your switch some interfaces/ports are shut down (default on some switches) and seem to be configured as UNI (UNI and ENI talk to NNI ports only). To enable them and make them switching universally:
enable
config
interface GigabitEthernet0/1-2
  no shutdown
  port-type nni
exit
write mem


This works, thank you. Now I can't get to make SFP ports work. They are working no compatibility issues I can get details from "show idprom interface" everything looks good. When I do "no shutdown" on SFP interface it doesn't go up, any ideas ?

Have you made sure the fiber strands are crossed?

Yes, I can see rx and tx power from both ends

(a) are you using Cisco optics? (b) how is your 3400 licensed? (it can have more ports than it's licensed to use.)
